# Could the U.S. Federal Reserve cancel the U.S. dollars held in foreign country's reserves?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, federal-reserve

Say the U.S. wanted to punish or disable some foreign power that had lots of U.S. dollar reserves. Don't those foreign power reserves sit on a ledger (or a Federal Reserve chartered bank's ledger) somewhere that the U.S. Federal Reserve could just set to zero or otherwise seize?

Comment: do you suppose that might affect the value of the other held assets, just a touch? It seems like your asking "_couldn't a husband punch his wife in the nose?_"; sure but there might be undesirable side-effects.

Comment: My question is literal, like is there anything physically stopping the Federal Reserve from doing this, like in a war-type scenario.

Comment: oh, in that case, no, and we've frozen assets before, eg. carter+iran 1979...

Comment: Are you asking if they can freeze money that is in the control of the federal reserve or asking if they can freeze money anywhere in the world?

Comment: @dandavis But, this question is regarding the Federal Reserve. Those assets were frozen by president Carter... The Fed is not exactly a part of the executive branch.

Comment: I think a question about whether it COULD be done really belongs on the Economics site. (I think there is one.)  If it could be done, then a question asking about potential consequences might be appropriate here.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you @jamesqf. I had been stuck finding a stack exchange because I was seeking out "government" or "civics" and this seemed like the closest one, so thank you for the pointer

Comment: @dandavis: IIRC, the Iranian assets that Carter froze were being held by US banks, not by the Iranian government, banks, or businesses.  Whether assets held in other countries were also frozen depends on the country and its politics.

Comment: Are you talking about cash, bank accounts, or bonds? The answer is a bit different for each... Purely for bank accounts this has been discussed on econ.SE as I remember, although not quite in these terms, see e.g. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/what-prevents-a-bank-from-simply-going-into-their-computer-system-and-adding-som?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And in more technical terms https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-reserves-move-between-the-12-federal-reserve-banks

Answer (score 3):

> Say the U.S. wanted to punish or disable some foreign power that had
> lots of U.S. dollar reserves. Don't those foreign power reserves sit
> on a ledger (or a Federal Reserve chartered bank's ledger) somewhere
> that the U.S. Federal Reserve could just set to zero or otherwise
> seize?

No.

The U.S. government under the contracts clause, which was devised in large part to prevent punitive governmental action directed at foreigners participating in U.S. commerce, cannot simply cancel or seize the assets of a foreign holder of U.S. assets because it wants to, and the Federal Reserve certainly lacks that power in its own right.

The U.S. government (apart from the Federal Reserve) could, however, declare war upon a country, or bring suit against it and obtain a court judgment, and seize those assets as an act of war, or to enforce a court judgment.

Answer (score 0):

**Partially.**

All dollar transactions are going through the US bank system - so the US can block particular dollar transactions. For example, by formally "freezing" accounts for some reason.

So, it, of course, cannot cancel - because account may be in some bank of other country. But it can definitely push this bank to block the particular account by freezing(or threatening to freeze) bank's correspondent accounts in the US banks.

That is the origin of de-dollarization process launched by some countries.

Comment: Thanks. How are dollars held in a foreign bank that isn't chartered or run by the Federal Reserve? Like, how does the Federal Reserve stop them from showing up one day and saying "We checked our ledger and we have 1 trillion US dollars", there has to be some mechanism by which the Fed Reserve can say "no you don't and we have the proof right here"

Comment: Very simple. You might claim whatever, but transactions *from* this account would go through the US financial system. Which would not accept them, if you claim something wrong. Also, such "claim" may lead to disconnection that particular bank from SWIFT.

Comment: Cash transaction don't, actually go that route. See how Iran has been paying Russia with dollars in suitcases.

Comment: Cash - of course, but we're not talking about cash here, as I understand. In fact, you almost cannot control cash in any currency not only US dollars.

Comment: But the OP asks about CANCELLING dollars held by other countries, which is an entirely different thing from freezing assets.  To take an existing case, the Iranian assets frozen by the US still exist (and IIRC generate income that is likewise frozen).  They could be unfrozen, given a change of government in either Iran or the US.

Comment: Hmm. US may arrest and confiscate such account, like some Venezuelian or the same Iranian. Confiscating looks very similar to nullifying.

Comment: @John_Krampf There were banks in the US long before the Federal Reserve existed, and it isn't needed to operate banks. If you deposit money in a bank there is a contractual agreement between depositor and bank that the depositor can get their money back - this is true in every country, and it doesn't rely on the Federal Reserve or any central bank having a record of deposits. The bank will keep a record of the deposit, and the depositor will also have a record, and the two should match. Deposits actually in the Federal Reserve are administered by the Fed, but on the same principle.